# oledb xlsx join without on condition

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, xlsx

I access an xls-document via oledb with c#. I have to join two sheets without any on-condition. I try to get any column-combination which is possible from those two sheets.

Under mssql I can do it using `ON 1 = 1` for the join-condition, but that doesn't work here.

Here are some variations i have already tried:

```
1. SELECT [Grid 1$].[FOO], [Grid 2$].[BAR] FROM [Grid 1$] LEFT JOIN
    [Grid 2$] ON 1 = 1    
2. SELECT [Grid 1$].[FOO], [Grid 2$].[BAR] FROM [Grid 1$] LEFT JOIN
    [Grid 2$] ON TRUE
3. SELECT [Grid 1$].[FOO], [Grid 2$].[BAR] FROM [Grid 1$] CROSS JOIN
    [Grid 2$]
```

Number 1 and 2 throw:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): JOIN expression not
>   supported.

Number 3 throws:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Fehler
>   E_FAIL(0x80004005) in IErrorInfo.GetDescription.

Is there any solution or workaround for this problem?

---

To point out what i am exactly looking for here is an example:

```
Sheet 1:
 1. foo
 2. bar
Sheet 2:
 1. jon skeet
 2. harry potter
```

The query should return:

```
foo jon skeet
foo harry potter
bar jon skeet
bar harry potter
```

I hope this points out my intent.

Comment: Are you have a column with same name in both tables to identify relationship of both worksheets? Using `JOIN` without `ON` clause is pointless, the exception tells you that supplied `JOIN` command is not valid.

Comment: No there are no columns with the same name. There is actually no relation between these two sheets. I will expand my question to point out what im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a LEFT JOIN with a 1=1 condition is pointless. From your explanation you are after a cartesian join (CROSS JOIN and FULL JOIN on some databases). You can do it without any join clause (old style join IOW):

```
SELECT [Grid 1$].[FOO], [Grid 2$].[BAR] FROM [Grid 1$], [Grid 2$]
```

Note: And always keep in mind that Excel is not a database.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what i was looking for. Using joins and complex statements made me forget about this simple way...